# string indices must be integers django rest framework

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I have a big serialized `json` field from which I'm trying to extract multiple keys then construct another `json` and send that via requests.

Example:

```
class ACtionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    logger = logging.getLogger('django')

    """
    API endpoint
    """
    queryset = Action.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ActionSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.OrderingFilter,
                       filters.SearchFilter, DjangoFilterBackend)
    filterset_class = ActionFilter

    # create new action for this workflow
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = ActionSerializer(data=request.data, context={'request': request})
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            encode_data = json.dumps(serializer.data)
            wanted_key = ['task', 'task_default', 'slug']
            new_action = {x: encode_data[x] for x in wanted_key if x in encode_data}
            print(new_action)
            workflow = json.dumps(new_action)
            response = requests.post(
                url='{}/workflows'.format(MISTRAL_URL),
                json=workflow,
                headers=headers
            )
            # logging.debug(f"{self.response}")
            return Response({'response': response}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The error is

`string indices must be integers`

Traceback:

```
File "/home/copser/.local/share/virtualenvs/api-IztWJwuB/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/copser/.local/share/virtualenvs/api-IztWJwuB/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/copser/.local/share/virtualenvs/api-IztWJwuB/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/copser/.local/share/virtualenvs/api-IztWJwuB/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/copser/.local/share/virtualenvs/api-IztWJwuB/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py" in view
  116.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/copser/.local/share/virtualenvs/api-IztWJwuB/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  495.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/home/copser/.local/share/virtualenvs/api-IztWJwuB/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
  455.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/home/copser/.local/share/virtualenvs/api-IztWJwuB/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  492.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/copser/Documents/Project/api/src/action/views.py" in create
  76.             new_workflow = {x: encode_data[x] for x in wanted_key if x in encode_data}

File "/home/copser/Documents/Project/NjiNN/njinn/api/src/action/views.py" in <dictcomp>
  76.             new_action = {x: encode_data[x] for x in wanted_key if x in encode_data}

Exception Type: TypeError at /api/v1/action
Exception Value: string indices must be integers
```

I'm a bit confused why is this happening, so can someone please explain what is happening here, thanks

Comment: Can you post the complete traceback? Or at least line number at which error is getting raised.

Comment: What is your `ActionSerializer` looks like ?

Comment: You've converted your data object to a string with json.dumps, then when assigning new_action this error gets raised. 'some_string'['foo'] will give you the same error. Dropping the json,dumps may fix it, or if request.data is a string you should be doing json.loads instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is telling you you must use integers as string indexes, i.e `"some string"[0]` works, `"some string"['test']` will raise the above.

That gives you a hint where to look! Namely, `encode_data` is a string generated by  `json.dumps`.

You can probably drop the `json.dumps`, or use `json.loads` instead if `serialiser.data` is a string.

In other words:

```
$ json.loads('{"foo": 123}')['foo']
> 123


$ json.dumps({'foo': 123})['foo']
> TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 1):

`json.dumps` returns a string, meaning `encode_data` is a string, not a dict.

if `serializer.data` is already a dict, use it as is, if it's a string use `json.loads(serializer.data)`

the error is getting triggered on this line:
`new_action = {x: encode_data[x] for x in wanted_key if x in encode_data}`

in python, strings are iterable, but can only be accessed through integer keys, like a list.

```
my_string = "01234"
my_char = my_string[3] # result is "3"
```

but you are trying to access it like this:

```
my_data = my_string["key"]
```

which doesn't work.

Comment: ah, well it is a dict, all ready, I'm over doing it, but thanks for the clarification